# Why can go take a gerund? (eg: go shopping; go fishing, go dancing)

Tags: syntactic-analysis, gerunds, intransitive-verbs, grammatical-roles, deverbal-nouns

I am trying to figure out why ***go*** can take a gerund, which is a verb doing the job of a noun, as an object yet the verb ***go*** is always intransitive and therefore cannot take an object. I need to make sense of this in order to explain to my class.

Comment: Why do you think "shopping", "fishing" and "dancing" are nouns, not verbs?

Comment: They resist adjectival premodification (*I like to go occasional fishing") and prefer adverbial postmodification ("I like to go fishing occasionally").

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do the -ing and to-infinitive "verbs" that follow catenative verbs always take the grammatical function of "noun"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/184320/do-the-ing-and-to-infinitive-verbs-that-follow-catenative-verbs-always-take-t) (Note that the 'go fishing' structure is called a 'phase structure' by CoBuild; contrast the verb + DO structure as in 'This involves stripping the engine'.)

Answer (score 2):

The verb *go* can take another verb in the *-ing* form following it, but that doesn’t make that *-ing* word a noun (nor *go* transitive). It is not. It is (usually) still a verb.

1. When you go **hunting deer**, here *hunting* is a verb.
2. When you go **deer hunting**, here *hunting* is a noun.
3. And when you go **hunting deer hunting hunters**, you presumably get one of each — or else the deer are out to get you. :)

I would personally avoid confusing people with the word “gerund”; it doesn’t explain what those cases shown above are doing.

The intransitive verb *come* works similarly. You can come running, but nobody ever came breathless running. They only ever come running breathlessly. Therefore those must be verbs not nouns. And they’re still intransitive.

> **Figuring** things out is harder than it appears.

*Figuring* is a verb here, not a noun, just like in your other case; that’s why it can have an object. “Gerunds” are only ever verbs. Deverbal nouns like *earnings* also exist, but since those are nouns they are not “gerunds”.

“Gerund” is not a part of speech. It’s just something a verb can do. It’s still a verb doing it.

> *Breathlessly running races* is not the same construction as *breathless race running* is.

There the first instance of the word *running* is a verb because it is modified by the adverb *breathlessly* and has *races* as its direct object. The second instance of *running* is a noun because it is modified by the adjective *breathless* and by the attributive noun *race*.  It has no direct object, nor can it, being a noun not a verb.

The matrix verb here is the tensed verb *is*. The syntactic constituent that serves as the subject of that main verb is the nonfinite verb phrase (or clause) *Breathlessly running races*. It is not a noun because phrases don’t have parts of speech.  That entire clause, not some individual word of it, is the subject of the verb *is*. The only noun in that clause is its direct object, *races*.

## Grade School “Grammar”: An Enduring Curse?

The simplified descriptions of English grammar that we use when teaching our second- and third-graders often deliberately conflate parts of speech like nouns, verbs, and adjectives with grammatical roles like subjects and objects, modifiers and predicates.

A part of speech can only ever apply to individual words alone, while a grammatical role doesn’t care how many words make up that single syntactic constituent.

This probably does little enough harm for its targeted audience, except that we never teach anything beyond that until and unless you take actual courses in linguistics, which is about as rare as hen’s teeth in the general populace.

So what is it ***really***?

### “Gerund” is not about parts of speech: it’s about grammatical roles.

- When a nonfinite verb phrase using that verb’s *-ing* inflection takes on the grammatical role of a subject or an object in the broader syntactic context, some people call that a *gerund phrase*.
- When the identical sequence of words instead takes on the grammatical role of a modifier, some people call that very same thing a *participial phrase*.
- Others have dispensed with this confusing Latin-derived terminology altogether, or fused it into a *gerund-participle phrase*.

But in all those cases it is still only ever a verb, whatever its grammatical role should work out to being.

## The fate of ex-verbs

You can “denature” the *-ing* verb of its verbal nature by converting it into an actual noun or adjective — or occasionally into an adverb, preposition, or conjunction.

Once you’ve done that, your *-ing* word is not a verb, only a “former” verb, or a word “converted” from a verb via “zero derivation”: it’s spelled the same but acts differently.

Some sources call these ex-verbs verbal or deverbal nouns and verbal or deverbal adjectives/adverbs.  Others call them gerundial nouns or participial adjectives/adverbs. The key point is that once their part of speech switches from verb to something else, different rules apply.

- A deverbal noun like *earning* can be made plural *earnings* through inflectional morphology. You can now have *various earnings*, or use it as an attributive noun as in *earning levels*. While it is still a verb, all that remains impossible. You cannot talk about “the plural” of *earning one’s daily bread* because that is still a verb. The verb isn’t a countable thing, nor even a thing at all.  The deverbal noun, however, is — or can be roped into being such.
- A deverbal adjective like *boring* becomes gradable, so a class might be very boring and one class might be more boring than another. You cannot do that while it is still a verb such as it is in *boring me to tears*. There would be no place to put *very* in *Somebody boring me to tears was not what I needed then,* because there *boring* is still a verb, not an adjective, so it can’t take *very* yet.

Comment: I'd say 'deer hunting' is a compound verb in 'go deer hunting'. Compare 'gone baby-sitting'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You might well be onto something. All I'm especially certain of is that *go* has an assortment of unusual properties when combining with other verbs, nonfinite forms variously in bare or *to* infinitive or *-ing* versions. *Kitty, go hunt mice outside. She won't/didn't go hunt mice when I tell/told her to. She'd go hunt/hunting mice whenever she could. She went to hunt mice but got distracted,* but this is ungrammatical: *She went *hunt mice in the barn.*

Comment: In the UK, [go + V {+ NP}] is less productive (sorry) than in the States. "Go fly a kite" is totally idiomatic in the obvious registers, "Go take a hike" is not unknown, but "Go have a look" becomes "Go and have a look".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The versions with *go and V* are plentiful here as well, so much so that I had to consciously omit reporting the many that sprang naturally to mind in my posted examples, hoping to avoid the condemnation typically drawn by the similar *try and V* forms.

Comment: Condemnation? 'What’s the BrE for “shotgun wedding”?' 'Ans: '“shotgun wedding”' is obviously of far greater value than your answer here (18:2). Doesn't it say somewhere 'Woe unto you when all men speak well of you'? Probably banned as non-PC now. // FWIW, I've snaffled your article and left the wedding party to their own devices.