# "this drug induces sleeping" or "this drug induces sleep"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, gerund-vs-infinitive, direct-objects, predicate-frames, deverbal-nouns

I seem to have heard both structures before, but I don’t understand which it would be.

In other languages the second verb would be in the infinitive, but I have heard things like "Josh hates running" from native speakers, making the *‑ING* version correct in at least that particular case. What about "Josh hates to run" with an infinite instead?

Could I get some clarification on whether one version sounds better than the other, or whether they have different meanings? Is there a general rule to be understood here, or is every valid verb combination of this sort idiosyncratic and unpredictable?

Comment: A related construction: ["Do not induce vomiting" (in section "if swallowed" on many poisons in the United States)](https://www.cvear.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/MIDASH-Forte-label.pdf)

Comment: There's not that much difference between making you sleep and making you sleepy when it comes to the end result, but there is a great deal of difference syntactically. But you can like to run, and you can like timed running, and you can like running the water before bed, and you can like to run the water a bit before you step into the shower — but you probably don't like running noses.:) Related: [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/366906),
[2](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/346877),
[3](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/508264),
[4](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/388099).